# Extracting Number from multiple strings in a loop

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I'm new to python and the python community and I was hoping someone on the platform could help me with the following. I'm trying to learn the Beautiful soup package from Python to scrape some data from the internet and to do some data analysis on those data. The thing I am stuck at is the following:

I am trying to extract prices from the following strings:

```
A = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 182,00</span>'''
B = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 92,00</span>'''
C = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 1820,00</span>'''
D = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 9,00</span>'''
```

Into the following format:

```
AA = "€182,00"
BB = "€92,00"
CC = "€1820,00"
DD = "€9,00"
```

I would like to make the expression as general as possible, so I can loop over more strings as well. 
Is there someone who can help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically create variables. But something like this helps?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

A = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 182,00</span>'''
B = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 92,00</span>'''
C = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 1820,00</span>'''
D = '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 9,00</span>'''


def get_text(html_string):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
    return (soup.text)

html_stringList = [A,B,C,D]
priceList = []
for var_string in html_stringList:
    priceList.append(get_text(var_string))

print(priceList)
```

**Output:**

```
['€ 182,00', '€ 92,00', '€ 1820,00', '€ 9,00']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that parses the string using a regular expression and returns the first match, this way you will be able to parse a string based on the regex that you provide.

*(You can ignore `# coding: utf-8`, I just added it so I can test it in the terminal as the file container the euro character.)*

```
# coding: utf-8
import re

def extract_text(regex, val):
  extracted = re.findall(regex, val)[0]
  return extracted

extr = extract_text("€ [\d]+,[\d]+", '''<span style="font:16px Arial; color:#993c00; font-weight:bold;">€ 182,00</span>''')
print(extr)
```